# Python Regular Expression Output with Up to Two Words

Tags: python

```
zillow_list = ['https://www.zillow.com/62347390?location=Phoenix%3C%23CA', 
    'https://www.zillow.com/82983250?location=Los%54Angeles%3C%43CA',
    'https://www.zillow.com/12917837?location=New%72York%54City%3C%27CA']
```

How can I create a python function such that we get the following output when given `zillow_list` as input?  The city name output can only be one or two words.  For example, the output for 'New York City' is 'New York'.

```
> city_find(zillow_list)
['Phoenix', 'Los Angeles', 'New York']
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Umm... why are your locations when you take into account the url encoded values: `['Phoenix<#CA', 'LosTAngeles<CCA', "NewrYorkTCity<'CA"]` - seems odd...

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use regexp, Python `urllib` has a url parser.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

def get_city(url):
    qs = urlparse(url).query
    location = parse_qs(qs)['location'][0]

    # This takes care of your maximum 'two words' requirement
    short_location = ' '.join(location.split(' ')[:2])

    return short_location

def city_find(urls):
    return [get_city(url) for url in urls]
```

Here it is in action.

```
zillow_list = ['https://www.zillow.com/62347390?location=Phoenix%3C%23CA', 
    'https://www.zillow.com/82983250?location=Los%54Angeles%3C%43CA',
    'https://www.zillow.com/12917837?location=New%72York%54City%3C%27CA']

city_find(zillow_list)
# Output: ['Phoenix<#CA', 'LosTAngeles<CCA', "NewrYorkTCity<'CA"]
```

Note that the output is a bit off the one you were asking for, but my guess is that you might have misformated your urls. These give the correct city names.

```
'https://www.zillow.com/62347390?location=Phoenix' 
'https://www.zillow.com/82983250?location=Los+Angeles'
'https://www.zillow.com/12917837?location=New+York+City'
```